# Could not resolve host error while adding targetserver

Tags: apigee

I want to add new targetserver but I am getting following error.

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: <TargetServer name=TS1><Host>test.jokeindex.co
m<
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \

{
    "fault": {
        "faultstring": "XMLThreatProtection stepDefinition XMLThreat: Execution
 failed. reason: Unexpected char while looking for open tag ('&lt;') character",
        "detail": {
            "errorcode": "steps.xmlthreatprotection.ExecutionFailed"
        }
    }
}
```

curl command:

```
curl -H "Content-Type:text/xml" -X POST -d \ "<TargetServer name="TS1"><Host>test.jokeindex.com</Host><Port>80</Port><IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled></TargetServer>" \ -u nisarg:mypwd https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/o/nisarg/environments/test/targetservers
```

Comment: Can the machine resolve and/or ping test.jokeindex.com ?

Comment: No. Request time out.

Comment: That is what your curl error is saying also.

Comment: Yes so I then used POSTMAN plugin of chrome and got the response.
Thanks Flauntster.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use single quotes around the data, since you are using double quotes within.

So try this instead:

```
curl -H "Content-Type:text/xml" -X POST -d  '<TargetServer name="TS1"><Host>test.jokeindex.com</Host><Port>80</Port><IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled></TargetServer>' -u nisarg:mypwd https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/o/nisarg/environments/test/targetservers
```

Comment: On windows single quotes was throwing some syntax error and I found on stackoverflow that we should use double quotes instead of single quotes.